# Getting similar space from a item on richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, line, richtextbox

I'm making an application and i need get the same interval of space from a line in many items (strings). My code is something like that

```
p = "";
int contaletras = 0;

int maxPalavra = 14; int xpto;

contaletras = item.Length;
xpto = maxPalavra - contaletras;
for (int i = 0; i < xpto; i++)
{
    p = p + " ";
}
StringBuilder m = new StringBuilder();
m.Append(item);
m.Insert(item.Length, p);

RTB_Exames.Text = RTB_Exames.Text + m.ToString() + " ";
```

So, my `item.length` is all the time 14 characteres. But 
i dont know why i have this result when in textvisualizer in c# i have this. I will show some image in this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tH_Qo3-GvhSEJrOXVsTzhIQVk/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tH_Qo3-GvhaTN5WUM1M2M3QVU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need a monospaced font, like Consolas.

Comment: You know i can i get it ?

Comment: The Font property of the RichTextBox control.  From the designer, select Consolas, or Courier New.

Comment: I understand now , when you said Consolas i dont see it like a type of Font. Thanks a lot, i try courier and Consolas and it Works. Really thank you :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the font in the visual editor for the TextBox control or set it via:

RTB_Exames.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");